# Google analytic with Funnel steps with dynamic view

Tags: google-analytics, seo

I am new to funnel setup for virtual Page view. I have an quick question for SEO experts...

[image]

As you know, the funnel has "Name " and "Screen/Page".

In following screen, I am wondering about track_Pageview values (e.g: 'inquirey-visitorname-completed'). Are they Funnel's name or "screen/page" values? Please let me know.

[image]

Thanks you guys in advance.

Comment: I would like to suggest you post this question in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

in your example(looks like it's example from [KissMetrics article](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/conversion-funnel-survival-guide/)) after "onBlur" JS-event happend on example, trackPageview method send virtual pageviews.
In Google Analytics at report "All Pages" you will see values like:
'/inquiry-visitorname-completed',
'/inquiry-country-completed',
'/inquiry-visitorstateprovince-completed',
etc.

In funnel settings you should use, for example, "/inquiry-visitorname-completed" **as "Screen/Page"**.

So, in the "Screen/Page" should be used any type of pageview(real or virtual), like '/thankyou.html', '/order/completed/', etc.

In the "Name" field you can use "Order Lists", "Get a Quote", and so on - this is just name of steps for GA funnels.